# Extract the minute value from the date

Tags: bash

I need to extract the minute value from the Linux "date" command.
The online guides are really confusing.
Can you help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
date +%M
```

This will print just the minute value and you can assign it to a variable with:

```
dat=`date +%M`
echo $dat
```

Comment: How do I assign the output to a variable. In this case I want to put it into a while condition, while [ ((5%$MINUTE)) -ne 0 ]

Comment: So, will this work? while [ ((5%$`date +%M`)) -ne 0 ] For some reason it's removing the back ticks around the date +%M.

Comment: OK, Thanks Benj.
while [ ((`date +%M`%5)) -ne 0 ]
Is working.

Comment: while [ $(('date +%M'%5)) -ne 0 ] I was missing a $ before the (...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 date +%M
```

For getting it directly .

or this

```
 date | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ":" -f 2
```

for getting it indirectly

Comment: @Benj just another method  :-)

Comment: On my system, that prints out the year, not the minute.

Comment: On my system, it's `date | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d ":" -f 2`

Comment: You don't even need `cut`. You can just go `date | awk -F: '{print $2}'`.